# javascript: iPhone select wheel causing page to scroll to top when touching dropdown

Tags: javascript, android, ios, iphone, zepto

I have a web app I'm developing (with zepto) which has several dropdown  elements on one form. On iPad and Android devices, everything is fine. On an iPhone however, when scrolling, if you touch a dropdown while scrolling, the page snaps back to the top. You can hold a finger down on the element and nothing happens until you start to drag.

It looks like maybe it's trying to open the select options wheel that's on iPhone but not on iPad or Android and it's moving the page in the process? The actual wheel itself isn't shown because you're dragging and not tapping. This may not even be the cause but it was a guess.

I'm not sure what to try to prevent it registering the scroll touch as an event to open the dropdown/snap to the top. What could be the cause or a possible workaround?

Below is a sample dropdown which I removed the classes from and renamed everything to "Field1" just to make it readable.

thanks for any input

```
 <label>DropDown Field</label>
    <div value="div_Field1" label="div_Field1">   
        <select id="Field1">
            <option value=""><span>None</span></option>
            <% _.each( data.Values, function( val ){ %>
                <option value="<%- val.Field1 %>"><span class="text-color-1 dib"><%- val.Field1 %></span></option>
            <% }); %>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, it wasn't a problem with iOS or the code. The web app I was developing for, Salesforce1, had a bug which was causing code to behave abnormally. It seems to have been fixed.